# get time since date in year, month, days, hour, minute, and seconds

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to get time from November 28, 2016 .
i want that time shows like it has been 1 year 2 month 6 days 17 hour 19 minute and 36 seconds.

```
var dateString = '11/28/2016';
var now = new Date();
var today = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var yearNow = now.getYear();
var monthNow = now.getMonth();
var dateNow = now.getDate();
var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6, 10),
    dateString.substring(0, 2) - 1,
    dateString.substring(3, 5)
);
var yearDob = dob.getYear();
var monthDob = dob.getMonth();
var dateDob = dob.getDate();
var time = {};
yearTime = yearNow - yearDob;
if (monthNow >= monthDob)
    var monthTime = monthNow - monthDob;
else {
    yearTime--;
    var monthTime = 12 + monthNow - monthDob;
}
if (dateNow >= dateDob)
    var dateTime = dateNow - dateDob;
else {
    monthTime--;
    var dateTime = 31 + dateNow - dateDob;

    if (monthTime < 0) {
        monthTime = 11;
        yearTime--;
    }
}
time = {
    years: yearTime,
    months: monthTime,
    days: dateTime
};
if (time.months < 9) {
    time.months = '0' + time.months;
}
if (time.days < 9) {
    time.days = '0' + time.days;
}

$('#cnt_year').text('0' + time.years);
$('#cnt_month').text(now);
$('#cnt_days').text(time.days);
```

it shows Year, month and days but how do i add hours and minute.

Comment: Your `dateString`  has no time. Are you going to assume 12MN?

Comment: Some problems are better solved with frameworks. Look at momentjs instead.

Comment: Some problems are better solved with frameworks. Look at momentjs instead.

Comment: momentjs's diff() function is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Some problems are better solved with frameworks. Look at momentjs instead.

Comment: @AadityaThakkar can you show example ?

Comment: @MukeshSoni   Look at the example in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given there are only 30 days in a month/all monnths.

```js
 var dateString = '11/28/2016';
 var now = new Date();
 var today = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
 var yearNow = now.getYear();
 var monthNow = now.getMonth();
 var dateNow = now.getDate();
 var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6, 10),
  dateString.substring(0, 2) - 1,
  dateString.substring(3, 5)
 );
  
 var nTotalDiff = Math.abs(now - dob);
 var oDiff = {};
 
 oDiff.years = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30 / 12);
 nTotalDiff -= oDiff.years * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12;
 
 oDiff.months = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30);
 nTotalDiff -= oDiff.months * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
 
 oDiff.days = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
 nTotalDiff -= oDiff.days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

 oDiff.hours = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
 nTotalDiff -= oDiff.hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;

 oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60);
 nTotalDiff -= oDiff.minutes * 1000 * 60;

 oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000); 
  
 console.log( oDiff );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use moment.js's diff and add functionality,

```
    const today = moment();
    const dateString = moment('11/28/2016');
    const diffYears = today.diff(dateString, 'years');  // diff gives you the difference between two days in integer.
    dateString.add(diffYears, 'years');   // to get difference in month now, you first need to add `diffYears` to the dateString, same follows for the further calculations.
    const diffMonths = today.diff(dateString, 'months');
    dateString.add(diffMonths, 'months');
    const diffDays = today.diff(dateString, 'days');
    dateString.add(diffDays, 'days');
    const diffHours = today.diff(dateString, 'hours');
    dateString.add(diffHours, 'hours'); 
    const diffMinutes = today.diff(dateString, 'minutes');
    dateString.add(diffMinutes, 'minutes'); 
    const diffSeconds = today.diff(dateString, 'seconds');
```

You can find more examples at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/